# Code-behind Gets Wrong RadioButton Value

Tags: radio-button, webforms

Like I wrote in the title, the code-behind gets the wrong value when I try to change the selection of a RadioButton.

**Dilemma.aspx:**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes, please." />
    <asp:ListItem Text="No, thanks." />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Ummm... maybe." />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:Button ID=""btnChoose" runat="server" text="OK" OnClick="btnChoose_Click" />
```

**Dilemma.aspx.cs:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int initialIndex = GetInitialIndex(); // Simplified for sake of question.
    rbList.SelectedIndex = initialIndex; // This works.
}

protected void btnChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selection = rbList.SelectedIndex; // This gets it wrong!
}
```

Instead of getting the newly-selected RadioButton, the code-behind still believes that the selected index is the initial index.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        int initialIndex = GetInitialIndex(); // Simplified for sake of question.
        rbList.SelectedIndex = initialIndex; // This works.
    }
}
```

Somebody posted this answer, but deleted it for some reason.
Whoever it is who posted this answer before me - it works!